# Struct initialization changes in C++ 20

Tags: c++, struct, c++20, initializer

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct Something
{
    int x;
    long y;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Something> k = std::make_unique<Something>(0, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

This program compiles with `g++ --std=c20`. Why?

I could not deduce from [this list](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) which change supports this.

Compilation fails with `g++ --std=c2a` for obvious reasons.

Comment: Perhaps [Allow initializing aggregates from a parenthesized list of values](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html)